# how to switch accounts automatically in meatamask

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

hello everybody I have an online vote application this application building on smart contracts, ganache, and web3.js . in this application each elector has an address from the ganache.
I want when the elector goes to vote he will give his privatekey and metamask take this private key automatically without going to click on metamask and import the address I need this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible by design.

The Metamask JS API (implementing Ethereum provider API) doesn't allow importing an account (or a read-only address) programatically.

See https://docs.metamask.io/guide/#account-management for more info.

Comment: what mean this my friend

Comment: @ZoubairELhattab It means that you cannot import the address programatically - you need a user to import it manually into MetaMask.

Comment: sorry if i bother , there are another solution or another application similar metamask can do this

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But I'd recommend editing your question and stating what goal are you trying to achieve (possibly user experience - so that it's easy for them to vote) and hopefully someone else will give a better answer.